# CoordinatorLayoutの中にViewを入れた際にCoordinatorLayoutのwrap_contentsが効かない

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

#### 問題

以下のようにCoordinatorLayoutを使用してレイアウトを組んでいるのですが、CoordinatorLayoutの中かつAppBarLayoutの外にViewを置いた場合、CoordinatorLayoutをwrap_contentsにしているにもかかわらず、Viewの下部がCoordinatorLayoutからはみ出てしまっています。（画像参照）

ViewPagerにはスクロール可能なFragmentを置く予定です。

原因が分かる方がいましたら、ご教授お願いします。

[image: 下にはみ出ている]

#### 試したこと

・ViewPager以外のViewも置いてみましたが、結果は同じでした
・AppBarLayoutの中に置いてみましたが、behaviorが正しく機能しなくなってしまいました
・AppBarLayoutとViewをLinerLayoutなどでくくってみましたが、同じくbehaviorが機能しませんでした

#### コード

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/FM_RootLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/colorBackground"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:id="@+id/FM_MainContents"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_contents">

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/colorBackgroundZ1">

            <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/FM_TabView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
                android:background="@color/colorBackgroundZ1"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                app:tabGravity="center"
                app:tabMode="scrollable"
                app:tabTextColor="@color/colorChar" />

            <View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="5dp"
                android:background="@drawable/shadow_up"
                android:translationZ="3dp"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

        <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/FM_Pager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="500dp"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
            app:layout_constrainedHeight="true"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/FM_Controller"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

えっと、最近、`CoordinatorLayout` をいじってないので、間違ってたらすみません。

これは多分、正常（仕様通り）なのではないでしょうか。

`ViewPager` は 500dp で高さが固定されていますが、下の余白にさらに別の `View`（例えば、ボタンストリップや、バナー広告など）を配置する場合を想定してみてください。

`CoordinatorLayout` の場合、スクロールすると、まず、`AppBar` が一緒にスクロールして消えて、その段階で 500dp のフルの高さの `Viewpager` の状態となって、その中でスクロールする形になるわけです。

だから、初期状態で、`AppBar` の分の高さは、下に配置した別の `View` の背後に隠れているのが正常になります。そのため、`CoodinatorLayout` の高さはレイアウト的に `AppBar` の分だけ上にズレていて、下の余白に追加した `View` がその高さからレイアウトされる必要があるわけです。

---

あと、ついでですが、`wrap_contents` ではなく `wrap_content` ですね。また、`app:layout_constraint*` は `ConstraintLayout` の子 `View` 用の属性なので、全て不要ではないかと思います。